# Sample Coreldraw projects do not get Imported

Tags: coreldraw

I have downloaded some sample corelDraw projects from different resources, which has sizes in the range of 1-10 MB, but, when i open them using corel menu's "File open" option it give me error "Either it is not importable using selected filter or this format is not supported" I tried alternatives ways to open these files but failure!

Please note that

1. These are the files with cdr extensions.
2. They got sizes in MB's whose range is mentioned above
3. How can I make these files usable!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import them File --> Import, 
Or maybe your Corel Version is lower then project files